# Transform predicate returning local variable by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stl, std

In the following code, I am trying to copy a `std::vector<char>`, into a `std::vector<uint8_t>`. To avoid compiler warning, I am doing explicit casting inside the predicate of `std::transform` instead of using `std::copy`, like this

```
std::vector<char> buf(10, 10);
std::vector<uint8_t> u(10);
std::transform(std::begin(buf), std::end(buf), std::begin(u),                                 
     [](uint8_t val)->decltype(*std::begin(u)){                                            
     return static_cast<decltype (*std::begin(u))> (val);                              
     });
```

For this code, I get compiler warning saying that I am trying to return a local variable `val` by reference.

Why is that and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Your lambda should be `[](uint8_t val) { return val; }`. There's no need for all the `decltype` complications.

Comment: @Praetorian Won't a conversion from `char` to `uint8_t` produce compiler warning on Clang, because `char` is signed on Clang.

Comment: I don't know, you're the one that wrote `uint8_t` as the parameter type :). If you want to avoid such warnings, then change it to `char val` and add a `static_cast` to the return statement. There's still no need for `decltype` anywhere.

Comment: Is it just a warning you get from your compiler? That code will exhibit Undefined Behavior, because you'll be returning a reference to a temporary in your lambda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is [right](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/849e5f69850f010b). In the return type of your lambda:

```
decltype(*std::begin(u))
```

dereferencing the iterator returned by [`std::vector<T>::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) returns `T&` or `T const&` depending on the `const` qualification of `u`. Secondly, your lambda exhibits Undefined Behavior because you are returning a reference to a temporary, `val`.

To solve your problems, you can use [`std::decay_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)

```
std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(u))>
```

---

Which [leads](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea46ef3586193ced) us to:

```
std::transform(std::begin(buf), std::end(buf), std::begin(u),                                 
     [](auto val)-> std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(u))> {
        return val;                              
     });
```

### ------------------------------------------------------

If the types are implicitly convertible, you can simply do:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> u(std::begin(buf), std::end(buf));
```

or, to an already created `u`:

```
u.assign(std::begin(buf), std::end(buf));
```

On the other hand, for some other complex type, a plain loop isn't bad:

```
for(const auto& k : buf)
    u.emplace( k.converted() ); //Assuming you must call a conversion function
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're actually looking for is the range constructor of `vector`:

```
std::vector<char> buf(10, 10);
std::vector<uint8_t> u(buf.begin(), buf.end());
```

This is both more efficient and easier to read than the solution involving `transform()`.

Comment: Sorry, I lied, the destination type is not exactly a `std::vector`. But it supports range iterators `begin` and `end`, so I called it such.